# Priority Queue sqaure root run time

Tags: priority-queue

I am having a Data Structures Exam and I am preparing from a list of review questions.  The question I am stuck on is as follows:

"Suppose your friend comes to you and claims that he has invented a super fast comparison based priority queue.  The speed of the priority queue is as follows ( n is the number of items currently in the priority queue ):
     a. insert a new item in O(sqrt(logn)) time
     b. extract (remove and return) the smallest item from the queue in O(sqrt(logn)) time.

Explain why your friend must be lying:"

From what I understand the running time of a standard priority queue is O(1) and O(n) for extraction.  I am having trouble understanding the question.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

O(1) and O(n) - its unsorted array realization, but you can sort or partically sort (binary heap for example ) the queue.
Best realization of binary heap has insertion or selection O(log(N)). But for for some special cases you can reach O(log(N)^1/2) or even loglog(N) - for example for intergers. But it your friend does not say anything about set - thats why he is lying.

Comment: so if he leaves out the "set" of the list of integers, we can't come to a conclusion that this is the case?  What is meant by "set" in this context?